# Spring Security PKCE configuration code_verifier missing in callback URL

Tags: oauth-2.0

I am configuring PKCE through Spring Security, following the official documentation. However, I've found that I cannot find the code_verifier in the callback URL, preventing me from obtaining the token.

Spring boot version 3.2.3
Spring security version 6.2.2

[This is my application.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kY4WQ.png)

[this is my SecurityConfig.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDjdW.png)

I am trying to figure out how to retrieve the code_verifier in the callback when configuring PKCE with Spring Security. If there's a mistake in my configuration, I'm also open to exploring other related methods. Thank you for your help.